# Can we show that if $T'$ is injective (surjective), then $T$ is surjective (injective)?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hahn-banach-theorem

If $T$ is a linear operator between vector spaces $X,Y$ and $T^\ast$ denotes the algebraic adjoint, i.e. $T^\ast:Y^\ast\to X^\ast,y^\ast\mapsto y^\ast\circ T$, it is easy to see that if $T$ is injective (surjective), then $T^\ast$ is surjective (injective). In particular, if $T$ is bijective, then $T^\ast$ is bijective.

Now I've read that if $X,Y$ are Banach spaces and $T':Y'\to X'$ denotes the topological adjoint, then $T$ is bijective if and only if $T'$ bijective. How can we show this and why is it important that we are dealing with Banach spaces and that we've replaced the algebraic with the topological duals?

And are we only able to show the equivalence or does it even hold that if $T'$ is injective (surjective), then $T$ is surjective (injective)?

Comment: What is $X'$ exactly?

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. $X'$ is the topological dual space of $X$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346560/show-t-is-invertible-if-t-is-invertible-where-t-in-bx-t-in-bx/346640#346640 .. for a longer answer to the bijectivity part of the question

Comment: see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346560/show-t-is-invertible-if-t-is-invertible-where-t-in-bx-t-in-bx/346640#346640

Comment: At the bare minimum, you would need some Hahn-Banach condition. Otherwise, if $X\neq 0$ is such that $X'=0$, then the zero map $X\to X$ has bijective dual, but it is neither injective nor surjective.

Comment: And likewise, if $X$ is as above and $Y\leq X$ is nonzero finite-dimensional, then $Y\to X$ is injective, but $X'\to Y'$ is not surjective. Of course, it is always true that if $T$ is surjective, then $T'$ is injective.

Comment: @daw Why did you delete your answer to the other question? I think your approach works: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4011183/47771.

Answer (score 2):

The implication: ``$T$ surjective  $\Rightarrow$ $T'$ or $T^*$ is injective'' is quite easy to prove:

Assume $T'f=T'g$. Then $(T'f)(x)=(T'g)(x)$ and $f(Tx)=g(Tx)$ for all $x\in X$. Since $T$ is surjective, $f=g$ follows. Same for $T^*$. Note that when dealing with continuous operators here, surjectivity of $T$ can be replaced by: image of $T$ is dense in $Y$.

The implication: ``$T$ injective  $\Rightarrow$ $T'$ surjective'' is false in general: take $T$ to be an injective compact operator between infinite-dimensional Banach spaces. Then $T'$ is compact as well, and the range of $T'$ is not closed. I have no idea/intuition about the algebraic dual $T^*$ for this implication.

The implication: ``$T'$ injective  $\Rightarrow$ $T$ surjective'' is false as well. Take $T$ compact with dense range, then $T'$ is injective, but $T$ has not closed range.

The implication ``$T$ bijective  $\Rightarrow$ $T'$ or $T^*$ bijective'' on the other hand is true, and can be proven by showing that $(T')^{-1}=(T^{-1})'$ and $(T^*)^{-1}=(T^{-1})^*$.

The implication ``$T'$ bijective  $\Rightarrow$ $T$ bijective'' is a consequence of the closed range theorem: By the closed range theorem, the range of $T$ is closed and the annihilator of the nullspace of $T'$, so $T$ is surjective. Injectivity of $T$ is clear. Here, $X,Y$ have to be Banach spaces.

Comment: (a) Maybe you got me wrong. It was already clear to me that the implication "$T$ is surjective $\Rightarrow$ $T^\ast$ is injective" holds. Do you claim that the converse is true as well? (b) Actually, I thought the implication "$T$ is injective $\Rightarrow$ $T^\ast$ is surjective" holds as well. In fact, if $y^\ast\in\mathcal N(T^\ast)$, then $$0=\langle x,T^\ast y^\ast\rangle=\langle Tx,y^\ast\rangle\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in X$$ and hence $$\langle y,y^\ast\rangle=0\;\;\;\text{for all }y\in\mathcal R(T).\tag1$$ If $T$ is surjective, then $\mathcal R(T)=Y$ and hence $(1)$ yields $y^\ast=0$.

Comment: Am I missing something? (c) What I really wanted to know is whether the converse implications in (a) and (b) hold as well. And, if they don't hold, how can we show that, if $X,Y$ are Banach spaces, it holds "$T$ is bijective $\Leftrightarrow$ $T'$ is bijective" (note that the algebraic dual $T^\ast$ is replaced with the continuous dual $T'$).

Comment: (a) I do not know (b) your proof is wrong: it proves $T$ surjective $\Rightarrow$ $T^*$ is injective. The converse is wrong at least for continuous duals. One can at best prove that the image of $T$ is dense, but it might not be closed.

Comment: (c) is a consequence of the closed graph theorem

Comment: (b) Sorry, I've mistakenly provided the proof of the wrong direction. The correct one goes as follows: Assume $A$ is injective. Let $x^\ast\in X^\ast$. Since $A$ is injective, $$\langle y,y^\ast\rangle:=\langle A^{-1}y,x^\ast\rangle\;\;\;\text{for }y\in\mathcal R(A)$$ is well-defined. By construction, $$\langle x,A^\ast y^\ast\rangle=\langle Ax,y^\ast\rangle=\langle A^{-1}Ax,x^\ast\rangle=\langle x,x^\ast\rangle\tag2$$ for all $x\in X$; i.e. $A^\ast y^\ast=x^\ast$.

Comment: At which stage does this proof fail when the algebraic duals are replaced by the topological ones? Shouldn't the same proof be valid?

Comment: $y^*$  might be unbounded (if, e.g., $A$ is compact)

Comment: (b) You're right. However, the proof should remain to be correct, if we assume that $X,Y$ are complete and $\mathcal R(T)$ is closed, since then $T^{-1}:\mathcal R(T)\to X$ is bounded by the bounded inverse theorem. Do you agree or am I missing something? In any case, I've read that the claim holds without these assumptions. So, maybe only my proof is not working. But how do we prove it then?

Comment: (a) The proof of the algebraic version of the other direction (i.e. if "$A$ is surjective, then $A'$ is injective") I've mistakenly provided in my former response to (b) should hold for general normed vector spaces $X,Y$ and $T$. Do you agree?

Comment: the implication ``$T'$ injective $\Rightarrow$ $T$ surjective'' is false as soon as $R(T)$ is not closed.

Comment: In your answer you wrote that $\mathcal R(T)$ is closed by the closed graph theorem. Why is that true? Doesn't the closed graph theorem only imply that $\{(x,Tx):x\in X\}$ is closed?

Comment: I meant the closed *range* theorem, sorry.

Comment: Ah, I see.

 (Please note that there is still one line where you are writing closed *graph* theorem.)

Comment: You wrote that injectivity is clear, but what is your argument? Is this correct: If $x\in\mathcal N(A)$, then $0=\langle Tx,y'\rangle=\langle x,T'y'\rangle$ for all $y'\in Y'$ and hence $x\in\mathcal R(T')_\perp$. Now, since $T'$ is surjective, $\mathcal R(T')=X$ and hence $\mathcal R(T')_\perp=\{0\}$. Thus, $x=0$.