# If there is a $x\in\ell^p\setminus\{0\}$ and $V\subseteq\ell^q$ with $\langle x,y\rangle=0$ for all $y\in V$, then $\overline V\ne\ell^q$?

Tags: functional-analysis

This should be quite obvious, but I struggle to find a formal proof: Let $1\le p<q\le\infty$ with $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$. We know that $\ell^q$ is isometrically isomorphic to $(\ell^p)'$ via $$\iota:\ell^q\to(\ell^p)'\;,\;\;\;y\mapsto\langle\;\cdot\;,y\rangle,$$ where $$\langle x,y\rangle:=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}x_ny_n\;\;\;\text{for }(x,y)\in\ell^p\times\ell^q.$$

> Assume $x\in\ell^p\setminus\{0\}$ and $V\subseteq\ell^q$ with $$\langle x,y\rangle=0\;\;\;\text{for all }y\in V\tag1.$$ Why can we conclude that $\overline V\ne\ell^q$?

Comment: Of course you meant to include the hypothesis $1/p+1/q=1$. Given that, this has nothing to do with $p<q$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be a real or complex Banach space, $x\in X\setminus\{0\}$ and $V\subseteq X'$ with $x\in V_\perp$. By the Hahn-Banach theorem, there is a $\varphi\in X'$ with $$\langle x,\varphi\rangle=\left\|x\right\|_X\ne0.\tag1$$ If $\overline V=X'$, then there is a $(\varphi_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq V$ with $$\left\|\varphi_n-\varphi\right\|_{X'}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag2$$ and hence $$0=\langle x,\varphi_n\rangle\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\langle x,\varphi\rangle\ne0\tag3;$$ which is impossible. This shows the even stronger result that even the closure of $V$ wrt the weak topology cannot be $X'$.

Answer (score 1):

An appropriate choice of $y\in \ell^q\setminus\{0\}$ among the ones that realise the equality case of Hölder's inequality, namely $y_n=\alpha_n\cdot\lvert x_n\rvert^{p/q}$ where $\alpha_n\cdot x_n=\lvert x_n\rvert$, will be in $\ell^q\setminus\overline V$, because for said $y$ $$\langle x,y\rangle=\lVert xy\rVert_1=\lVert x\rVert_p\lVert y\rVert_q\ne0$$

Comment: Are you using the Hahn-Banach theorem for the existence of $\alpha$ (resp. $y$) or does  this follow from something more elementary here?

Comment: In the case $p=q=2$, i.e. when we are dealing with a Hilbert space $H$, we simply need to observe that $\left\|\tilde x-v\right\|_H^2=\left\|\tilde x\right\|_H^2+\left\|v\right\|_H^2\ge1$, where $\tilde x:=x/\left\|x\right\|_H$, for all $v\in V$ and hence $\tilde x\not\in\overline V$, right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d No Hahn-Banach: $\alpha_n$ is just the appropriate real/complex number of modulus $1$ that eliminates the sign of $x_n$ (I'm not sure if you are considering real or complex Banach spaces). The fact that $y\in \ell^q$ is just by its definition.

Comment: I'm consider a complex Banach space. What do you say about my comments on the Hilbert space case?

Comment: @0xbadf00d The fact that $\overline V\subseteq\ker\langle x;\bullet\rangle$ is just continuity of the map $\langle\diamond;\bullet\rangle:\ell^p\times \ell^q\to\Bbb C$, $\langle x,y\rangle= \sum_k y_kx_k$, any way you may want to see it.

Comment: But you agree that this shows $\tilde x\not\in\overline V$, right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d I don't quite understand your point and I don't quite see what this has to do with my answer.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how this would generalize if we replace $\ell^p$ and $\ell^q$ by an arbitrary Hilbert or Banach space and its dual. My point is that the Hilbert space case should be provable as in my comment above (and I would like to know whether you agree or not) and for the Banach space I don't see how we can proof the existence of a functional similar to the function $\langle\;\cdot\;,y\rangle_H$ induced by $y$ in the Hilbert space case without using the Hahn-Banach theorem (which immediately yields the existence of such a functional).

Comment: That's why I've tried to understand how you define $\alpha$ in a more general sense.

Answer (score 0):

$\langle x,-\rangle\colon\ell^q\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous linear functional on $\ell^q$.  $V$ is contained in the proper closed subspace $(\langle x,-\rangle)^{-1}(\{0\})$ of $\ell^q=(\ell^p)'$ so cannot be $\ell^q$ itself: There is a continuous linear functional on $\ell^p$ which doesn't annihilate $x$, namely $y\in(\ell^p)'=\ell^q$ with
$$
y_i=
\begin{cases}
\frac{\lvert x_i\rvert^{p}}{x_i} & x_i\neq 0\\
0 & x_i=0
\end{cases}.
$$

Comment: I don't think we can conclude that $V$ is closed. $V$ is *not* the inverse image of $\{0\}$ under $\langle x,\;\cdot\;\rangle_H$; it is only *contained* in it.